# How to manual trigger close ng-bootstrap popover

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How to set the popover not to close automatically on blur?
I want to only manually close this popover

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xt18mj

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this : `[autoClose]="false"`

Example :

```
<button type="button" class="btn mr-2" placement="bottom" [autoClose]="false"
        ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." popoverTitle="Popover on bottom">
  button 1
</button>
```

For more information : [Documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples)